# why Python sleep causes code to run slower

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to test opencv decode video speed and cpu occupancy rate.
this is a simple test.

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
    while True:  
        st = time.time()  
        cap.read()
        print(time.time() - st)

        # time.sleep(0.05)
```

cap.read()  always cost  5ms.
but the weird is if i add a  "time.sleep" at the end of loop,   cap.read()  's time-consuming become instable, cost 5ms - 15ms,  10ms mostly. This makes me confused.

i  change the code like this

```
k = 0
while True:
    st = time.time()
    # cap.read()
    for i in range(1000000):
         k += 1
    print(time.time() - st)
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

result is same， so this has nothing to do with cap.read

Comment: Not an expert but I think sleep causes the program to return control to the os to run something else. So next time ur program has to run it has to wait for its turn. Whereas if it was running continuously it would not have to wait a d therefore ur program runs faster. Someone can correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `sleep` call guarantees* you than your code will sleep **AT LEAST** the amount you specify, but it can sleep for more.

Normally processor is distributed between tasks in "chunks" (today normally tens of milliseconds). When the chunk expires the CPU is forcibly taken from your task and given to others if they need it too.
When you sleep what happens is that your code will release the CPU earlier and it will regain it at next time your code is available for running (i.e. if enough time it will have been passed) but this check has a granularity of a chunk, and that's the reason `sleep` may take more.

Note that if your system has more than one CPU there will be multiple of these chunks executing at the same time and this makes predicting exactly when your code will be waken after a sleep unpredictable (if you sleep a tiny amount it may wake up earlier than a chunk has passed not because others released their chunk earlier, but because you got this time a different CPU, for example).

If you need exact timing sleep is not the answer (and also the OS must support exact timing, something that normal OSes don't do at application level).

If your code doesn't release the control and the operation requires much less than a time slicing chunk then statistically the measure using the wall clock is reasonably correct. However there are other clocks (measuring how much CPU time your code used, not how much time passed on the wall clock). One way is to simply run your code on a lot of data and call it using `time` command line utility (on Linux).

On Python there is a specific `timeit` utility for this kind of measures.

(*) It can also actually sleep for less, but that doesn't happen in normal conditions

Comment: so the real time of the code cost is still 5ms, the way of test time-consuming is not correct ( proper) in this case?

Comment: @user5829693: if you don't release the control and the operation requires much less than a time slicing chunk then statistically the measure is reasonably correct. However there are other clocks (measuring how much CPU time your code used, not how much time passed on the wall clock). One way is to simply run your code on a lot of data and call it using `time` utility (on Linux).

Comment: i want to know cap.read cost time,   time.time() only surround the  cap.read, but sleep make the print time changed

Comment: @user: if you want to know how much CPU time `cap.read` takes then you need to use cpu clocks, not wall clock (what python `time` measures). If you want to know how much wall clock time passed then using python `time` is the correct way. However both CPU timings and even more wall clock timings depends on a lot of external and basically unpredictable factors (synchronizations with other thread or devices, CPU scaling, variable system load, scheduler "smart" handling of CPU distribution etc.) so it's well possible that the number will not be fixed.